# Batch script : for /F does nothing after executing a command

Tags: windows, batch-file

**The goal of this script is to display every WiFi devices with their keys, from the computer's saved networks.**

expected output :

```
<device_name1> : <key>
<device_name2> : <key>
<device_name3> : <key>
<device_name4> : <key>
```

This is the current script :
(it displays only the first 4 characters of both the devices and the keys)

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
goto :main


:getKey
for /F "tokens=2 delims=: usebackq" %%B in (`netsh wlan show profiles name=%1 key=clear ^| find "Key Content"`) do (
        set _clear_key=%%B
)
goto :eof


:main
for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%A in ('netsh wlan show profiles ^| find "User Profile"') do (
    set _profile_name=%%A
    set _profile_name=!_profile_name%:~1!
    
    set _clear_key=aaaaaaa
    
    call :getKey !_profile_name!
        
    echo !_profile_name%:~0,4! : !_clear_key%:~0,4!
)

pause
goto :eof
```

Current output :

```
Free : aaaa
TP-L : aaaa
Bbox : aaaa
...
```

I guess that the variable isn't correctly applied in the command and nothing is looped. However, I already used this syntax for other scripts and it should work.

I'm quite lost searching why this doesn't work T^T

---

- The command `netsh wlan show profiles name=!_profile_name! key=clear | find "Key Content"` works inside the first loop, but I can't interact with the key (Example below)

```
Free :
    Key Content            : v6v...
TP-L :
    Key Content            : 844...
Bbox :
    Key Content            : 7pf...
...
```

(script used)

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%A in ('netsh wlan show profiles ^| find "User Profile"') do (
    set _profile_name=%%A
    set _profile_name=!_profile_name%:~1!
    
    echo !_profile_name%:~0,4! :
    netsh wlan show profiles name=!_profile_name! key=clear | find "Key Content"
)
pause
```

- I already tried with and without usebackq for both "for /F" loops (and the other options)
- same with the `:getKey` part inside the first loop
- same with and without EnableDelayedExpansion (and using %var%, !var!, %1, %%B, %%K, ...)

I hope I haven't just made a dumb error.
This project is not important so, please don't spend/waste too much time trying to solve my problem.

Comment: What's with the `%` in `set _profile_name=!_profile_name%:~1!` and `echo !_profile_name%:~0,4!`? That shouldn't be there.

Comment: Take a look at this batch : [Wifi Passwords Recovery.bat](https://pastebin.com/Ntc8SZLU)

Comment: thank you @SomethingDark the `%` was indeed useless, but this didn't fix the issue.

Comment: @Hackoo I just noticed from the link you sent that the `=` wasn't escaped in the command. Now it works just fine. Thank you :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue has been solved thanks to @Hackoo in the comments of my original question.

I just didn't escape the `=` in the command `netsh wlan show profiles name=%1 key=clear ^| find "Key Content"`

Here's the final script if anyone wants it :

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
goto :main

:getKey
for /F "tokens=2 delims=: usebackq" %%B in (`netsh wlan show profiles %1 key^=clear ^| find "Key Content"`) do (
        set _clear_key=%%B
        set _clear_key=!_clear_key:~1!
)
goto :eof

:main
for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%A in ('netsh wlan show profiles ^| find "User Profile"') do (
    set _profile_name=%%A
    set _profile_name=!_profile_name:~1!
    set _clear_key=No password
    
    call :getKey !_profile_name!
    
    echo !_profile_name:~0! : !_clear_key:~0!
)
pause
exit /b
```

Answer (score 0):

The following batch file code can be used to get the WLAN key on PCs running English Windows:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%G in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\netsh.exe wlan show profiles 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "User Profile"') do for /F "tokens=*" %%I in ("%%H") do for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%J in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\netsh.exe wlan show profiles name^="%%I" key^=clear ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "Key Content"') do for /F "tokens=*" %%L in ("%%K") do echo Key for wlan %%I is: %%L
endlocal
```

`cmd` replaces all commas, semicolons, equal signs and no-break spaces by normal spaces in set of **FOR** on not being within a double quoted argument string. For that reason it is necessary to escape also all equal signs in set of third **FOR** with `^` to interpret them literally. This code works even for wlan network names and security keys containing a space, a colon or an exclamation mark.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `find /?`
- `for /?`
- `netsh /?`
- `netsh wlan /?`
- `netsh wlan show /?`
- `netsh wlan show profiles /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Read the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul` and `|`. The redirection operators `>` and `|` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal characters when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded command line with using a separate command process started in background with `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /c` and the command line within `'` appended as additional arguments.